# Android Https web service communication (SSL / TLS 1.2)

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, tls1.2

In my Android application I've got to communicate with a https web service and read the response.

I've informed the server configured **SSL** with **TLS 1.2**.

I am using the following sample code to connect with the service (https get request), but only the devices that runs **Android 5.0** or above can successfully communicate and read the response....

All the other devices below that version (Android 5.0) can't communicate and thrown IOException at the time when trying to establish connection...

```
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try 
    {        
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("https://domain.co.uk/services/pay.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2"));

        response = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
        String decodedResStr = URLDecoder.decode(responseString, "UTF-8");  

        Log.v("AppState", "Response: " + decodedResStr);
    }  
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("AppState", "Exception: " + e.getMessage() )
    }
```

**OR**

```
    // HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://domain.co.uk/services/pay.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2");
        //urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("AppState", "Exception: " + e.getMessage() )
    }
    finally
    {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

**Question 1**

Would like to know if I am doing anything wrong in here (if any additional parameter is missing in my code that will support older versions of Androids than 5.0 to support TLS 1.2 web service communication) ?

**Question 2**

I just googled and found this [DOCUMENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:TLS/SSL_support_history_of_web_browsers).

There it says the minimum supporting browser in ANDROID to communicate with TLS 1.2 is "GOOGLE Android 5.0 OS Browser". So is it the same restriction applying when trying to connect by the code (Apps)?

if so what would be the minimum Android version I should support if want to communicate with this web service (the minimum version of android that support TLS 1.2 web services)?

**Sample exception stack traces are as follows**

***Android 2.2 Simulator***

```
    11-06 12:51:01.885: W/System.err(352): java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: I/O error during system call, Unknown error: 0
    11-06 12:51:01.895: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeconnect(Native Method)
    11-06 12:51:01.895: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:316)
    11-06 12:51:01.895: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.getSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:168)
    11-06 12:51:01.905: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
    11-06 12:51:01.915: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1152)
    11-06 12:51:01.915: W/System.err(352):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:253)
    11-06 12:51:01.915: W/System.err(352):  at com.serviceapp.WSHelperHttpURLConnection.executeAndroid(WSHelperHttpURLConnection.java:93)
    11-06 12:51:01.915: W/System.err(352):  at com.serviceapp.HttpPage$1$1.run(HttpPage.java:69)
    11-06 12:51:01.915: W/System.err(352):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

***Android 3.0 Simulator***

```
11-06 12:56:22.917: W/System.err(447): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
11-06 12:56:22.927: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
11-06 12:56:22.927: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:485)
11-06 12:56:22.927: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
11-06 12:56:22.927: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:167)
11-06 12:56:22.937: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
11-06 12:56:22.937: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:428)
11-06 12:56:22.937: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
11-06 12:56:22.937: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
11-06 12:56:22.937: W/System.err(447):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
11-06 12:56:22.947: W/System.err(447):  at com.serviceapp.WSHelperHttpURLConnection.executeAndroid(WSHelperHttpURLConnection.java:93)
11-06 12:56:22.947: W/System.err(447):  at com.serviceapp.HttpPage$1$1.run(HttpPage.java:69)
11-06 12:56:22.947: W/System.err(447):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

**EDITS**

This is the full stack trace when use Robert's MySSLSocketFactory class implemention with an Android 4.4.2 AND Android 5.1.1 device.

```
11-06 14:26:46.962: W/System.err(14700): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol TLS1.2 is not supported
11-06 14:26:46.985: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.checkEnabledProtocols(NativeCrypto.java:879)
11-06 14:26:46.985: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.setEnabledProtocols(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:807)
11-06 14:26:46.985: W/System.err(14700):    at com.serviceapp.MySSLSocketFactory.createSocket(WSURlCon.java:99)
11-06 14:26:46.986: W/System.err(14700):    at com.serviceapp.MySSLSocketFactory.createSocket(WSURlCon.java:1)
11-06 14:26:46.986: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:131)
11-06 14:26:46.986: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
11-06 14:26:46.986: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-06 14:26:46.987: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-06 14:26:46.988: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-06 14:26:46.988: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-06 14:26:46.990: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
11-06 14:26:46.990: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
11-06 14:26:46.991: W/System.err(14700):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
11-06 14:26:46.991: W/System.err(14700):    at com.serviceapp.WSURlCon.executeAndroid(WSURlCon.java:33)
11-06 14:26:46.992: W/System.err(14700):    at com.serviceapp.HttpPage$1$1.run(HttpPage.java:74)
11-06 14:26:46.992: W/System.err(14700):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the Android Developer documentation TLS 1.2 is available and enabled on devices with API level 20+ (Android 4.4 Wearable):

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html

I assume non of your test devices uses that API level therefore you got the result that only 5.0 devices can connect.

My personal experience is that some 4.4 devices support TLS 1.2 however it is not enabled. You can try to enable it by calling `setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"})` on the used SSLSocket.

An elegant solution doing so is implementing an own SSLSocketFactory using the Proxy pattern:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

    public MySSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
        super();
        this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public SSLSocket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort)
            throws IOException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
        return socket;
    }
```

You can use it this way:

```
    ...
    urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new MySSLSocketFactory(urlConnection.getSSLSocketFactory()));
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the answer. I've just done a test using "MySSLSocketFactory" class you defined here with an Android device that runs Android Version 4.4.2 and gets exception message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol TLS1.2 is not supported". I will add the full stack trace under edits in my question.... Also as an aditional test, the device default web browser (chrome and android web browser both) can access the web service hosted url without any problem.

Comment: Also the same exception with Android 5.1.1 device.

Comment: Looks like I missed a 'v': correct should be `"TLSv1.2"`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Works well in Android Version 4.4.2 and 5.1.1 devices... Thanks and was very helpful....

Comment: @bdevloper have you found out?

Comment: Nope,But In my case It were be solved by server side. And from now I Use Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kotlin version of the answer from Robert, which fixed the problem in my case:

```
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.Socket
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

class MySSLSocketFactory(socket_factory :SSLSocketFactory):
      SSLSocketFactory()
{
    val sslSocketFactory :SSLSocketFactory

    init
    {
        this.sslSocketFactory = socket_factory
    }

    override fun getDefaultCipherSuites(): Array<String>
    {
        return this.sslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites()
    }

    override fun createSocket(socket: Socket?, host: String?, port: Int, autoclose: Boolean): Socket
    {
        val socket: SSLSocket = this.sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoclose) as SSLSocket
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(arrayOf("TLSv1.2"))
        return socket
    }

    override fun createSocket(host: String?, port: Int): Socket
    {
        val socket: SSLSocket = this.sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port) as SSLSocket
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(arrayOf("TLSv1.2"))
        return socket
    }

    override fun createSocket(host: String?, port: Int, local_host: InetAddress?, local_port: Int): Socket {
        val socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, local_host, local_port) as SSLSocket
        socket.enabledProtocols = arrayOf("TLSv1.2")
        return socket
    }

    override fun createSocket(host: InetAddress?, port: Int): Socket
    {
        val socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port) as SSLSocket
        socket.enabledProtocols = arrayOf("TLSv1.2")
        return socket
    }

    override fun createSocket(address: InetAddress?, port: Int, local_address: InetAddress?, local_port: Int): Socket
    {
        val socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, local_address, local_port) as SSLSocket
        socket.enabledProtocols = arrayOf("TLSv1.2")
        return socket
    }

    override fun getSupportedCipherSuites(): Array<String>
    {
        return this.sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()
    }
}
```