# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer on 4.4.2 device (works on 6.0.1)

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with getting this error when I'm performing network calls inside my app. Main problem is that same code works on Android 6.0.1 device, but on 4.4.2 device, I'm getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188)
at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

where I'm unable to request data from server.

If you need more data, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the answer provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33567745/3202633) by Robert

Comment: Thanks, that guided me to the solution!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Key here is to force TLS 1.2 protocol, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection) link here.

Only thing that I needed to correct here is to force TLS 1.2 protocol directly, like this:

```
private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

    private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        super.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}); // force to use only TLSv1.2 here
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidCheung Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @robigroza may i know, where do i have to use this code. Please, thanks in advance.

Comment: @robigroza it didn't work, got SSL handshake exception failed error.