# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)

Tags: android, ssl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

### before api level 24 my code is working fine but it is giving me error on api level 24( 7.0 Nougat). I am not getting what's going wrong with my code.

First Approach is here :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <network-security-config>
   <base-config> <trust-anchors> <certificates src="system"/>
   <certificates src="user"/> </trust-anchors> </base-config>
   <domain-config> <domain includeSubdomains="true">xyz.com</domain>
   <trust-anchors> <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/> </trust-anchors>
   </domain-config> </network-security-config>
```

Inside manifest file :

`android:network Security Config = "@xml/network_security_config"`
I have included `network_security_config` inside `res/xml/network_security_config` and `ca` certificate is inside `res/raw/my_ca.pem`

Second Approach is here :

```
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
 import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;  
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme; 
 import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry; 
 import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory; 
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 
 import java.io.IOException; import java.net.Socket; 
 import java.net.UnknownHostException; 
 import java.security.KeyManagementException; 
 import java.security.KeyStore;
 import java.security.KeyStoreException; 
 import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 
 import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException; 
 import java.security.cert.CertificateException; 
 import java.security.cert.X509Certificate; import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager; 
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager; 
    public class ExSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory { 
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
      public ExSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws 
         NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,KeyStoreException,
         UnrecoverableKeyException {
         super(truststore);
     TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() { 
     public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)  
     throws CertificateException {
     } public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)    
     throws CertificateException {
      } public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
     { 
return null; 
} 
}; 
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {
     x509TrustManager }, null);
 } public ExSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext
     context) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
     KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
 super(null); 
sslContext = context; 
} @Override public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
     UnknownHostException {
 return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
     autoClose); 
} @Override public Socket createSocket() throws
     IOException {
 return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(); 
}
     public static HttpClient getHttpsClient(HttpClient client) { 
try{
     X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() 
{ 
@Override
     public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String
     authType) throws CertificateException { }
 @Override public void
     checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws
     CertificateException {
 }
 @Override public X509Certificate[]
     getAcceptedIssuers() { 
return null; 
}
 }; 
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); sslContext.init(null, new
     TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null); SSLSocketFactory
     sslSocketFactory = new ExSSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
     sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
     ClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager =
     client.getConnectionManager(); SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry =
     clientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry();
     schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
     return new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager,
     client.getParams()); 
} catch (Exception ex) 
{ return null; 
} } }
```

While making http connection :

```
public String CallWebService(String url, String soapAction, String envelope){


final HttpClient httpClient = ExSSLSocketFactory.getHttpsClient(new DefaultHttpClient());
    HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 150000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 150000);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), true);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setHeader("soapaction", soapAction);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    String responseString = "";
    try
    {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(envelope);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        ResponseHandler<String> rh = new ResponseHandler<String>()
        {

            public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
            {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] b = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                out.append(new String(b, 0, b.length));
                return out.toString();
            }
        };

        responseString = httpClient.execute(httppost, rh);
        Log.d("Response is here....", "responseString :  " + responseString);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // close the connection
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return responseString;
}
```

Still I am getting error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer 01-24
>   10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   01-24 10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>   01-24 10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 01-24
>   10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 01-24
>   10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 01-24
>   10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
>   01-24 10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>   01-24 10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
>   01-24 10:28:03.182 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
>   01-24 10:28:03.183 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>   01-24 10:28:03.183 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
>   01-24 10:28:03.183 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>   01-24 10:28:03.184 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>   01-24 10:28:03.184 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
>   01-24 10:28:03.184 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
>   01-24 10:28:03.184 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at srd.gshelp.GSSoapConWSDL.javaHit(GSSoapConWSDL.java:180) 01-24
>   10:28:03.184 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   srd.gshelp.GSSoapConWSDL.access$0(GSSoapConWSDL.java:144) 01-24
>   10:28:03.185 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   srd.gshelp.GSSoapConWSDL$TaskAsync.doInBackground(GSSoapConWSDL.java:215)
>   01-24 10:28:03.185 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   srd.gshelp.GSSoapConWSDL$TaskAsync.doInBackground(GSSoapConWSDL.java:1)
>   01-24 10:28:03.185 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 01-24 10:28:03.185
>   32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 01-24
>   10:28:03.186 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   01-24 10:28:03.186 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   01-24 10:28:03.186 32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 01-24 10:28:03.187
>   32251-474/com.neosoft.meconnect W/System.err:     Suppressed:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

Kindly help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888852/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-connection-closed-by-peer-on-4-4-2-device-works-on

Comment: @Saurabh that solution isn't working for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have set **TLS enabled** from the server side.

Comment: Both server and client protocols are same. then also i am facing this issue. This is my code. pls help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946350/okhttp-android-websocket-and-jetty-server-connection-with-ssl/

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue, same `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` is throwing at the time of API call.

but in my case, the following was the issue

my `device` was `connected` to the `wifi` but wifi router was `not` having the `internet` connection and then the `exception` was thrown

Comment: It is not good to downvote without any reason and please try once the scenario I have posted and if it is now thrown the  `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` then downvote

Answer (score 1):

Do you have used Okhttp library ?
It is very good library for network calls. You can handle this exception it that also.

I had similar issue and i have managed it with this :

```
public static OkHttpClient getHttpClientForFile() {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
                .build();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .build();
    }
```

I don't know whether it is good or not, but it is working for me.

The class you have used `SSLSocketFactory` may produce error after publishing app on play store or play store may give you warning to change your code.

You can find `Okhttp` library from https://github.com/square/okhttp.