# Android 7.0 : 'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception, httpsurlconnection

When I am trying to access a 'https' web service from my app , it is giving a '**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer**' error. The same Web Service works fine in the Chrome browser through.

This issue is happening only on Android 7.0, It works fine in Android 6.0 & 5.0.

The Server is CA certified , not self-signed.

Comment: I have answered about the same issue in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459978/8240915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use the extended SSLSocket class to include all Protocols and Cipher Suites in order to overcome this issue . The solution lies in the GetProtocolList() & GetCipherList()

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder enableAllProtocols(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
    try {
        client.sslSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactoryExtended(), provideX509TrustManager());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e("OkHttpTLSCompat", "Error while setting Protocols", exc);
    }
    return client;
}
```

SSLSocketFactoryExtended Class file

```
public class SSLSocketFactoryExtended extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLContext mSSLContext;
    private String[] mCiphers;
    private String[] mProtocols;

    public SSLSocketFactoryExtended() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(null,null,null);
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return mCiphers;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return mCiphers;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(mProtocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(mCiphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(mProtocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(mCiphers);

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(mProtocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(mCiphers);

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(mProtocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(mCiphers);

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(mProtocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(mCiphers);

        return ss;
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        mSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        mSSLContext.init(km, tm, random);

        mProtocols = GetProtocolList();
        mCiphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    protected String[] GetProtocolList() {
        String[] protocols = { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"};
        String[] availableProtocols = null;

        SSLSocket socket = null;

        try {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();

            availableProtocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new String[]{ "TLSv1" };
        } finally {
            if(socket != null)
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }

        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableProtocols, protocols[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                resultList.add(protocols[i]);
        }

        return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    protected String[] GetCipherList() {
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        SSLSocketFactory factory = mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
        for(String s : factory.getSupportedCipherSuites()){
            resultList.add(s);
        }
        return resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked great. The server was an old WIndows 2003 server. With no support to TLS 1.2

Comment: by the way, how to use this?

Answer (score 2):

try use this code, it work for me :

```
 private static void initializeSSLContext(Context mContext){
    try {
        SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and don't forget to usr google security library :

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.6.2'
```

Comment: you can add it in onCreate on Application class or you can add it before the call of your service

Comment: got any ideas how to add this code to Cordova/Ionic app?

Comment: sorry man i don't know, i didnt program in Ionic before but if you can make a function then add the call of the function before service call(when you call the api to connect with the server)