# firebase storage and firebase cloud firestore data retrieve and storing problem to remote access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, remote-access, datastore, data-retrieval

Currently I am facing some issues with firebase data retrieving on android my project to be more specific. The problem is retrieving image from firebase storage and also storing data on firebase cloud firestore. Actually I have written all the code for these features in my project and I didn't face any problems the code worked properly. But the thing is when my project partner pulled that same code from github master branch (which I have pushed earlier) to code on his set of features on our project he can't access my coded features. Thus facing above described problems...

**EDIT**

Currently facing Exception

```
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/farmersapp-31e06.appspot.com/o/user_image1%2F1112.jpg
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@201516028@20.15.16 (100400-309763488):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@201516028@20.15.16 (100400-309763488):16)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:405)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequestStart(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:250)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:72)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:122)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Could you please share more details or any error message you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error message it seems that there is an issue with the SSL Handshake. I would suggest checking that you're not behind an SSL proxy and you may have enabled TLS at server side.

You may find useful this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422204/12265927) regarding the certificates.