# App from APK crashes when map trying to initialize

Tags: android-studio, apk, google-maps-api-2

When i run app trough Android Studio it works perfectly. But when i run it from apk release or debug it crashes on map initialize with issue:

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

API Key: AIzaSyBGDr2AfW0_cH_qhU-EnwCBFir-BKtfgQc

Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): null;

    FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.techacademy.demomaps, PID: 1406 
                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1478)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzg$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.techacademy.demomaps.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:392)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zzg(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze.zzmH(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzg.zznO(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzc.zznQ(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But on other devices APK works perfectly

> Also when starting the app Google Play Market stops working

Comment: So on a "real phone" it crashes, but in the emulator works OK?

Comment: @rogerdpack I try it on a real tablet, real phone and few emulators, and apk crashes only on a tablet

Comment: Does the tablet have GPS?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, thanks to support from Google:

I had an almost identical problem, except in the line:

```
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): null;
```

I could see the package name of my application after `null;`

The problem for me was the same, it only did not work on my test device, but it worked everywhere else, included the emulator. My test device was running KitKat (API level 19).

So things to check are:

1. The value of the API key, usually in the string resources file is actually in the 'release' strings resource file. Since there are these different files which are used respectively for debug and release apk builds.
2. To make sure that the `minSdkVersion` is 19 or earlier, as per the device that is not working.

After those, and contact with Google support, we realized that de app would not crash and the map would show with debug mode but I would get another crash on this line of code for an https request I was making for another reason:

`ufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {`

So, apparently this was my real problem. As in the words of Adam from Google support:

*"I suspected that it was related to the version of OS; and with that specific SSL error it seems to be illuminated here."*

*"By default, TLS v1.2 isn't enabled on Android until 5.0 (presumably because it didn't exist yet); though devices prior to that usually have the capability to enable it because of security patch updates. Unless you specify in your code to force TLS1.2, there will be a mismatch in SSL protocols and requests will fail."*

And he pointed me out to this response:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/33567745/3202633

I followed it and was able to fix my problem! As I understand, what this response suggest is to enable TLS1.2 in this API level in a custom `SSLSocketFactory` class, which is supported, but not enabled by default. And I suppose this security protocol is needed to run Maps communication, and in debug mode  it is handled differently.

I hope this helps you or anyone that comes across this strange thing.